# Unable to run jobs on CFNCluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have setup the CFNCluster and was able to run jobs on it before. But when I try to run now I am getting the below error. I am using the default scheduler SGE. kindly please help me resolve the issue.

```
[root@ip-00-00-0-000 ec2-user]# qsub hellojob.sh
Unable to run job: job rejected: your user id 0 is lower than minimum user id 100 of cluster configuration
warning: root's job is not allowed to run in any queue
Exiting.
```

Comment: Can you paste the code "hellojob.sh" here just mask any credentials that code might have?

Comment: when i execute it as root i am getting the above error. But it works fine when i run as  ec2-user [ec2-user@ip-00-00-0-000 ~]$ qsub hellojob.sh
Your job 15 ("hellojob.sh") has been submitted

Comment: do you know why  its rejecting my job when i try to run as root. thanks.

Comment: @nadish Grid Engine doesn't allow the root user to submit jobs. That's just the way the software is written. Not sure if there is a way to stop that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The min_gid min_uid is responsible for "minimum user id"

Just enter `qconf -mconf` and modify min_gid and min_uid to 0

You can see all options by entering: `qconf -sconf`